# Errors when building Linux compat-wireless and Linux backports

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, debian

```
root@debian:~/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486/build M=/root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-486'
  CC [M]  /root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1/compat/main.o
In file included from /root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:64:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1/include/linux/compat-3.4.h:58:20: error: redefinition of ‘eth_hw_addr_random’
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/etherdevice.h:165:20: note: previous definition of ‘eth_hw_addr_random’ was here
make[5]: *** [/root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1/compat/main.o] Ошибка 1
make[4]: *** [/root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1/compat] Error 2
make[3]: *** [_module_/root/dr/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-486'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I used [these instructions](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation).

I get this Error with a newer, now renamed, version of backports:

```
root@debian:~/dr/backports-3.12-1# make
make[5]: `conf'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /root/dr/backports-3.12-1/compat/main.o
  CC [M]  /root/dr/backports-3.12-1/compat/compat-3.3.o
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/swiotlb.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/dma-mapping.h:14,
                 from /root/dr/backports-3.12-1/backport-include/asm/dma-mapping.h:3,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/dma-mapping.h:68,
                 from /root/dr/backports-3.12-1/backport-include/linux/dma-mapping.h:3,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/skbuff.h:32,
                 from /root/dr/backports-3.12-1/backport-include/linux/skbuff.h:3,
                 from /root/dr/backports-3.12-1/compat/compat-3.3.c:13:
/root/dr/backports-3.12-1/backport-include/linux/swiotlb.h:12:29: error: static declaration of ‘swiotlb_nr_tbl’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/swiotlb.h:27:22: note: previous declaration of ‘swiotlb_nr_tbl’ was here
make[8]: *** [/root/dr/backports-3.12-1/compat/compat-3.3.o] Error 1
make[7]: *** [/root/dr/backports-3.12-1/compat] Error 2
make[6]: *** [_module_/root/dr/backports-3.12-1] Error 2
make[5]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you modify these sources? Anything special about your setup?